# Springboot test vs commandLineRunner gives different result

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, neo4j

Here's MVCE: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j

I added to Person entity method:

```
public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
    if (this.movies == null) {
        this.movies = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.movies.add(movie);
}
```

In **test** i added:
In the setup:

```
    keanu.addMovie(matrix);
    personRepository.save(keanu);
```

In one of **tests**:

```
Person p = personRepository.findByName("Keanu Reeves");
```

In debug mode here i clearlly see that p has movies collection when fetched.

After changing code from github test it looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Transactional
public class MovieRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Movie matrix = new Movie("The Matrix", 1999, "Welcome to the Real World");

        movieRepository.save(matrix);
        Person keanu = new Person("Keanu Reeves", 1964);
        personRepository.save(keanu);
        Role neo = new Role(matrix, keanu);
        neo.addRoleName("Neo");
        matrix.addRole(neo);
        keanu.addMovie(matrix);
        personRepository.save(keanu);
        movieRepository.save(matrix);
    }

    /**
     * Test of findByTitle method, of class MovieRepository.
     */
    @Test
    public void testFindByTitle() {

        String title = "The Matrix";
        Movie result = movieRepository.findByTitle(title);
        Person p = personRepository.findByName("Keanu Reeves");

        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(1999, result.getReleased());
    }

    /**
     * Test of findByTitleContaining method, of class MovieRepository.
     */
    @Test
    public void testFindByTitleContaining() {
        String title = "*Matrix*";
        Collection<Movie> result = movieRepository.findByTitleLike(title);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(1, result.size());
    }

    /**
     * Test of graph method, of class MovieRepository.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGraph() {
        Collection<Movie> graph = movieRepository.graph(5);

        assertEquals(1, graph.size());

        Movie movie = graph.iterator().next();

        assertEquals(1, movie.getRoles().size());

        assertEquals("The Matrix", movie.getTitle());
        assertEquals("Keanu Reeves", movie.getRoles().iterator().next().getPerson().getName());
    }
}
```

But if i make this:

```
  @Bean
    CommandLineRunner demo(PersonRepository personRepository, MovieRepository movieRepository) {
        return args -> {
        personRepository.deleteAll();
        movieRepository.deleteAll();

        Movie matrix = new Movie("The Matrix", 1999, "Welcome to the Real World");

        movieRepository.save(matrix);

        Person keanu = new Person("Keanu Reeves", 1964);

        personRepository.save(keanu);

        Role neo = new Role(matrix, keanu);
        neo.addRoleName("Neo");

        matrix.addRole(neo);

        keanu.addMovie(matrix);
        personRepository.save(keanu);

        movieRepository.save(matrix);


        Movie result = movieRepository.findByTitle("The Matrix");
        Person p = personRepository.findByName("Keanu Reeves");
    };
}
```

I see that p has not any movies. Why the difference? The code is the same as in test.

Comment: Possibly the test is wrapped by a transaction and the command line runner isn't. Add your test class.

Comment: I gave you link to github code and all changes i've made are described here in the question. So in the test i added in the setup: ```keanu.addMovie(matrix);
    personRepository.save(keanu);``` And in one of tests i added ```Person p = personRepository.findByName("Keanu Reeves");```

Comment: Normally good practice (and manners) to provide all relevant code in your question. As noted previously however, the test runs in a transaction so that is likely the reason for the difference.

Comment: Changing to: ```@Bean
    @Transactional
    CommandLineRunner```Does not fix that unfortunately. I tried providing all the code -> MVCE + all my changes. I will post also test after the changes i described. Thanks

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` there is not going to work. If that is the problem (and you can verify it it is by making the test non-transactional) then move the logic in command line runner to a transactional service class and call that from command line runner.

Comment: I've added the code from test class after all my changes i described

Comment: I've added: ```@Service
@Transactional
public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>``` And now it works fine - thanks, you were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with neo4j however would guess that it the fact that the test runs in a `@Transaction` and the code executed by command line runner does not.

Therefore remove the logic from command line runner to some place where it can be wrapped in a transaction, either a service class or application listener.